# Write a query to select a column with a additional letter

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I have a table with a id column, My query is

```
select id from tb_abc where title='xyz'
```

the result is

```
1
3
6
8
```

But what i want is to add a letter to id selected value
like

```
1d
3d
6d
8d
```

The letter d is fixed and declared in the query. Kindly guide.

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select concat(id,'d') as id
from tb_abc 
where title='xyz'
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/30679)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT(id,'d') AS id FROM tb_abc WHERE title = 'xyz'
```

This will work for you.

Earlier as posted query for MSSQL.

Comment: @jave.web earlier i have posted query for MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

lets say you declared it by a variable like that

```
$id = 'd' ;
```

then your query will be

```
 select concat(id,'$id') as id
 from tb_abc 
 where title='xyz'
```